# "[Key]" attribute supposed to set the column as primary but its not, EF code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Shouldn't [Key] attribute sets the database field as primary key ? I have a class already defined, later when I tried to set the primary key by putting [Key] attribute, the Add-migration command does not show any changes in up() or down() method. So does it means primary key has to be declared at the beginning and cannot be changed ?

I tried to create a test class {id,name} with no primary key, once the database was updated, later when tried setting the id field as primary key its not seeing the change in Add-Migration, what I'm missing ?

Comment: What is the name of the property you are adding the `[Key]` attribute to? And the name of the class?

Comment: Name of the class is `Test`, trying to update `Id` as `[Key]`

Comment: If you created a class with a field called `ID` (or `TestID`) , it will already be a key by [convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962). Adding the tag later does nothing new. What does the database show?

Comment: To verify it, I created the `Test` class with no `[Key]` for `Id`. In the table there were no primary key (I mean it does not show the key icon on the left side of the column in management studio). But after adding the attribute it does nothing.

Comment: Entity Framework cannot work with tables that don't have a key, if EF created the table then it absolutely has a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, Entity Framework decides a primary key property if you don't tell it which one to use. In order, this is how it chooses:

1. If you have a property called `Id`.
2. If you have a property called `ClassNameId` (i.e. your class is `Book`, the property will be `BookId`.)
3. Any property (or multiple properties for a compound key) that have the `[Key]` attribute.

And all of this can be overridden in the `OnModelCreating` method of your context.

So what has happened for you is that your existing `Id` property was already chosen as a primary key and adding the attribute makes no difference.

See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information on how this works.